# How to get a number from a list of numbers by using + or - operations

Tags: algorithm, binary, numbers

In my question, we are given a number and list of numbers and we are supposed to get the first number from the given list of numbers by using the operations +  or -

For Example:
-1 is the target number
1 2 3 5 are numbers given to get -1
solution should be -1+2+3-5 = -1
or -1-2-3+5 = -1

Limits for target number is from -180 to +180 and the limit for list of numbers is from 2 to 20

To find the solution what kind of algorithm should be used? If I want to use generate all the possibilities will it be efficient? And is the any binary solution of this problem?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If there are no more than 20 numbers then just a simple "brute force" approach should be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number of possibpe variants is `2^20`; Let's generate all numbers from `0` to `2^N`. Binary representation of these numbers will be 00000(20 zeroes), 000...01,0000.10,...,1111(20 ones). Imagine, that each zero is minus and one is a plus.

```
    int target = -1;
    int[] numbers = new int[20];
    Arrays.fill(numbers, 0);

    numbers[0] = 1;
    numbers[1] = 2;
    numbers[2] = 3;
    numbers[3] = 5;
    for(int i=0;i<(1<<20);i++) //masks from 00...00 to 11...11 (from --...--- to ++...+++)
    {
        int sum=0;
        for(int bit=0;bit<20;bit++)
        {
            if(((1<<bit)&i)>0)
            {
                sum+=numbers[bit];
            }
            else
            {
                sum-=numbers[bit];
            }
        }
        if(sum==target)
        {
            System.out.print(target+" = ");
            for(int bit=0;bit<20;bit++)
            {
            if(((1<<bit)&i)>0)
            {
                System.out.print("+"+numbers[bit]);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("-"+numbers[bit]);
            }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
```

Output:
-1 = -1+2+3-5-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-0