# C++ algorithm that returns all possible combinations of given numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to find all possible combinations of numbers.

for example: Input 1 2 3 4 5

Output 
1,
2,
3,
4,
5,
21,
31,
32,
41,
42,
43,
51,
52,
53,
54,
321,
421,
431,
432,
521,
531,
532,
541,
542,
543,
4321,
5321,
5421,
5431,
5432,
54321

(every number should be this ordered - from biggest to lowest)

I have an sorted array. I'm trying to write these numbers, it works perfectly fine but input with multiple same numbers like 3 3 2 2 1 not working good.

Bad thing is, that this needs recursion.

my base algorithm looks like this: (its more complicated but this is base structure)

```
extract(arrWithNumbers, PrintingArray) {

    For(i = 0; 0 < Numbers in array; i++) {
        if (numbers == i + 1) print(PrintingArray);
        PrintingArray[i] = arrWithNumbers[i];
        extract(arrWithNumbers, PrintingArray);
    }
}
```

Is there any known algorithm that can help me?

It's not only finding all possible combinations using

[image: Combination formula]

Thanks, for time and help.

Comment: Do a web search for "next combination", you should find some examples. If not, I can post my own version of such a function.

Comment: Number of all combinations = 2^numbersCount. Iterate over all binary numbers from 00.000 to 111.11 with `numbersCount` digits, 0 means omit number, 1 means take. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18586864/2104560   - the only difference is replacing + or - to concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int next_combination(size_t *I, size_t k, size_t n)
{
size_t i, j;
    i = k-1;                            /* find next element to increment */
    while(I[i] == (n-k+i)){
        --i;
        if(i == (size_t)-1){            /* if done */
            for(i = 0; i < k;  i++)     /*  return with initial combination */
                I[i] = i;
            return(0);
        }
    }
    I[i] += 1;                          /* increment element */
    for(j = i+1; j < k; j++)            /* create increasing string */
            I[j] = I[i]+j-i;
    return(1);                          /* return with new combination */
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
int    A[5] = {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
size_t I[5];
size_t i, k, n;
    n = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);         /* n things */
    for(k = 1; k <= n; k++){            /* n things k at a time */
        for(i = 0; i < k;  i++)         /* create initial combination */
            I[i] = i;
        do{                             /* display combinations */
            for(i = 0; i < k; i++)
                printf("%2d", A[I[i]]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        while(next_combination(I, k, n));
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done with some bit magic:

```
std::vector<int> vec {5, 4, 3, 2, 1};
int n = vec.size();
int cap = 1 << n;
for( int i=1; i<cap; ++i )
{
    for( int j=0; j<n; ++j )
    {
        if( i & (1<<j) ) cout << vec[j] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

go through 1 to 2^n, and let the bits represent if the number is present or not